# ssnonpartest test for nonparametric inference for multivariate data - interpretation

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis

I know the test is the correct one for my data but I'm struggling to interpret the results in a way I can coherently report. Using the example from the paper (https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v076i04):

```
Performing the Subset Algorithm based on Factor levels  
The Hypothesis of equality between factor levels 3 6 8 9 is rejected  
The Hypothesis of equality between factor levels 6 8 9 is rejected  
The Hypothesis of equality between factor levels 3 6 9 is rejected  
All appropriate subsets using factor levels have been checked using a closed
multiple testing procedure, which controls the maximum overall type I
error rate at alpha= 0.05
```

*In this example, a significant result is obtained between every set of three factor levels, as well as between the two treatments “3” and “6”’. Thus, the procedure has provided a comprehensive list of significances between treatment* (quote from the paper)

I understand the first part, that *The Hypothesis of equality between factor levels 3 6 8 9 is rejected* signifies that there is a difference between all factor levels. However I can't understand the next parts with regard to the explanation given in the quote. Could anyone help?

Comment: I've updated the formatting - the backticks ``` need to be on a new line (at least to end a block).

Comment: Thank you for the help!